# Manage List of Image in Asp.Net MVC Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to create an Asp.Net MVC 5 (Razor) view and controller capable to handle a list of Images.

Suppose a model like this one (the data are stored in a database and loaded with EF)

```
public class Game
{
   public Guid Id {get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string ImageUrl {get; set; }
   public ICollection<Screenshot> Screenshots { get; set; }
}

public class Screenshot
{
   public Guid Id {get; set; }
   public Game Game {get; set; }
   public string Title {get; set; }
   public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to:
1) create a page where the user can Create a Game and add one or more screenshots. 
2) create a page where the user can Edit a Game info and add/remove any of  screenshots.

Do you have any suggestion or example ?

Thanks

Comment: This seems like an overly broad question.

Comment: I found only example of uploading multiple images with multipart and <input multiple> which does not fit

Answer (score 0):

-To Add 1 or more screenshots, you might require using Ajax.BeginForm(...){}
-You might need an ability to add multiple images,[use ICollection to get save multiple images, after save, return the saved image data using the onSucccess event.

-For Editing, use the same logic, have a remove button on each image using ajax, then on success, remove image from screen.
Use same logic for adding new screenshots.

Using Ajax will also allow you to easier create effect for adding/ deleting images.

You can save images as I explained above to the db or even to a local temp folder that will be removed when the user clicks a save button, ect